# SP2013 and SPServices

Tags: spservices, canvasjs

I am looking for a way of putting CanvasJS charts generated with use of SPServices into the Webpart page.
What I did so far:

- Created webpart page(SPDesigner>SitePages>Webpart Page)
- Added table to it.
- In table added `<div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>`
- and linked scripts on the bottom of the page:

  ```
      <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == "function") {MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();}</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
      </table>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../SiteAssets/Jquery/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../SiteAssets/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../SiteAssets/SoG.css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/Jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/jscript" src="../SiteAssets/Jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/CanvasJs/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/Scripts/managementDashboard.js"></script>
  ```

got following error in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://00.000.00.00:00000/sites/ZZZZZ/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.jQuery.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.js:8706jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:8136ao.fn.SPServices @ jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js:19(anonymous function) @ managementDashboard.js:39jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ jquery.js:3048jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ jquery.js:3160jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.js:433completed @ jquery.js:104
```

When I put the same scripts into the .aspx page (SPDesigner>SitePages>Page>ASPX Page) all is fine. Script is jQuery script and looks like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){(..Code..
               $().SPServices({
                        webUrl: "http://00.000.0.00:000/sites/ZZZZZ/",
                        operation: "GetListItems",
                        async: false,
                        listName: "RIA",
        )
        });
```

Adding or removing webUrl makes no difference. 
I am trying to avoid creating aspx page and displaying it in page viewer on webpart page... 
Any idea how to use SPServices with Webpart page?

Comment: It seems like you have an extraneous comma and closing parenthesis after `listName: "RIA"` Is there other code missing? I would also try linking the scripts above your JQuery. Is your tale in a content editor web part? What is your script in?

Comment: The same code works perfectly fine in .aspx page (not webpart). I am not using content editor web part, linkin script on the bottom of the page. Script is to get data from list and generate chart on <div id="chartContainer2">

Comment: I really would always put scripts above the web part. SharePoint's finicky about it.  I don't think it's going to fix this problem though, since the problem is a cross-domain request. I've had this when specifying a port, but defining `webUrl` has always fixed it for me.